# Randomizing Alert view text for Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am new to programming. I am having trouble finding out what all is wrong with this. It is an alert view that i am trying to randomize the text displayed in the message.

```
-(void)alert:(id)sender{
int randomNumber;
randomNumber = (randomNumber() %3 + 1);
NSLog(@"%i", randomNumber);

if (randomNumber == 1) {
    self.YouWin.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Win"];
}
else if (randomNumber == 2) {
    self.YouWin.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Lose"];
}
else if (randomNumber == 3) {
    self.YouWin.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tie"];
}
NSLog(@"%@",YouWin);
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Hello" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",YouWin] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
button.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: and your problem is...

Comment: Here `message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",YouWin]`

Comment: Anoop has the answer. As a tip, don't use stringWithFormat like you do here `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Win"];`. Simply using `@"You Win" would be better.

Comment: When asking a question, please include a description of the actual problem ('it doesn't work' doesn't tell us anything useful!), how it currently behaves, the expected behavior, and include any error relevant error messages. Without that info, you're depending on us simply guessing at *both* the problem and the solution.

Comment: Also what is `randomNumber()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Anoop noted you are using `stringWithFormat` but you're not providing a format string at all.

You should do

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"You Win"];
```

but that's extremely redundant, although correct, and it's totally equivalent to just using `@"You Win"`.

Also an advice for the general approach on the problem. Instead of having a big `if-else` statement, it's better to store all your string into a data structure and then randomly access to it.

In code this would translate to

```
NSArray * outcomes = @[ @"You Win", @"You lose", @"Tie" ];
int randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(outcomes.count);
NSString * randomOutcome = outcomes[randomIndex];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Hello"
                                               message:randomOutcome
                                              delegate:self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
button.hidden = YES;
```

Note the usage of `arc4random_uniform()` that gives you back a random number between 0 and the argument provided, excluded.

Comment: To be precise, `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Constant string"]` is "fine" (i. e. it works correctly), it's just that it's superfluous.

Comment: That's what I said: *redundant*. Not wrong. I edited the answer to make it clearer it anyway.

Comment: @H2CO3: not 40. it was +6/-2 ;(

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Huh, didn't look at that. So -56? :(

Comment: @H2CO3: yes, but hopefully Still i have +215 for today.

Comment: What are you guys talking about? :D

Comment: Thanks a lot Petronella, I decided to go with yours.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Hello" 
                                               message:self.YouWin.text 
                                              delegate:self 
                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

You needed text-value stored in `YouWin`, but you passed the YouWin object itself.

**Note:* you can use `arc4random()` for generating random numbers.

Comment: Please add why. The OP mentioned being new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

There are many good suggestions; I agree with AKB8085.

Replacing the `randomNumber()` with `arc4random()` will help at compile time. 
But you might want to **re-think implementing a random number generator.** The reason is in fairness to your user.  I pose the question, “Is it fair to assume you want your user to guess a number with this large of a number range?”

**Did you Know?**

Using the arc4random(3), rand(3), or random(3) you are using a C function.
You are asking the user to guess a number with the following ranges:

1. `arc4random(3)` = `0` to `4294967296`
2. `rand(3)` and `random(3)` that top out at a `RAND_MAX` of `0x7fffffff` `(214748647)`

**To help in answering your question, answer the following requirement questions:**

1. Is there a min/max range restraint?
2. What type of compelling delays will happen 
      by using [`arc4random(3)`, `rand(3)`, or `random(3)`](http://nshipster.com/random/)?
3. Is using `NSArray` like in the [Fisher–Yates_shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) a better answer?

**SUGGESTION:**
Read an article on random numbers and `NSArray`.

**NOTE:**
Random numbers tend to task the compiler and your user experience will be hindered.

Comment: The user does not appear to have a chance to guess the number at all, so much of this is rather irrelevant. Otherwise it might have been better posed as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
randomNumber = (randomNumber() %3 + 1);
```

with

```
randomNumber = arc4random() %3 + 1;
```

Also use this...

```
if (randomNumber == 1) {
self.YouWin.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Win"];
}
else if (randomNumber == 2) {
self.YouWin.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Lose"];
}
else if (randomNumber == 3) {
self.YouWin.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tie"];
}
NSLog(@"%@",YouWin);


UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Hello" 
                                               message:self.YouWin.text 
                                              delegate:self 
                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];
button.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: Why random number will not meet 1/2/3 ?

Comment: If you generate the number like that, you guarantee that it will always be 1, 2 or 3. Don't be paranoid

Comment: ya.. @GabrielePetronella... you're right... i missed the mod sign with a divide...... thanks.... :)